# Is there any way to check a cookie's origins

Tags: cookies

My question is simple, and yet I couldn't find an answer to it anywhere. Is there any way to dynamically trace the page that sets a certain cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you store that information on the client- or server side. E.g. you cookie is a session cookie you can save the origin while creating the session. On the client side you could track that with a custom plugin/add-on.

Comment: You see, the problem is that I couldn't find certain cookies in the Set-Cookie headers of the page that could set them and the IFrames that it loaded. I am 100% positive that these cookies got set on page load. I want to find out where was it they came from.

Comment: If possible disable JavaScript in your browser than you know that the cookies are not created by JavaScript. In all other cases try using wireshark or some proxy software to sniff your network traffic. That should not be too hard.

Comment: Sniffing traffic is sadly not an option, as the website in question uses https.

Comment: If you own the site and you can access the private key this is no problem as long forward security is not enabled.

Comment: Also, if a cookie was set by a JavaScript, would it be possible to track it like I can track normal pages that set cookies by their Set-Cookie headers?

Comment: You could simply search for document.cookie

Comment: You don’t need to “sniff traffic”, just use the network panel of your browser’s developer tools – if the cookie is set via a HTTP header for one of the requested resources, you _will_ find it there.

Comment: In Firebug / Firefox you can pin the network events, so the requests won't be deleted after a reload or redirection.